# Flattened array representation for a Binary Tree data structure

Tags: c++, arrays, null, binary-tree

I happened to come across a flattened array representation for a Binary Tree data structure, where all the values on the tree are stored in an array that corresponds to an index tree.

I was wondering how to store null value at the array indices where there is no leaf node. I am assuming that the reference was in Java. In C++, how do we obtain a null value that does not equal 0. Should we use an array of pointers instead? One which allows the pointers to point to node values (if they exist) or assume a `nullptr` (when node value is null).

I do not plan to use NULL value from C++ as it equates to 0 integer, which will cause conflict in case of an integer array.

Please let me know if you need clarification.

[image: Example Image]

Comment: You can circumvent the problem by requiring that the last layer is filled left-to-right, in which case you simply need to know how long the filled prefix of the array is (=size of the tree).

Comment: You can store pointers to dynamically allocated objects. If you want to avoid dynamic allocation, you can store `std::optional<T>`, which holds `T` inside itself.

Comment: The property Norrius refers to means it is generally referred to as a "binary heap", and the process of ensuring the nodes are stored to guarantee this constraint is sometimes referred to as 'heapifying' the array. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap

Comment: Review: Why was this Q downvoted? I think it isn't that bad. Though a code sample of what was tried could be helpful.

Comment: If your array contains elements of `int` there is no other way as assuming a certain `int` value as invalid (and handle it respectively). If `0` is not a reasonable candidate, you could use `-1` or anything else which you don't consider as valid value for a node. If all `int` values are potentially valid than you have to store something else paired with your values e.g. a `bool`. This is similar to `std::optional<T>` which was already suggested by @Evg.

Answer (score 1):

Use -1.

No, seriously.

There is even at least one platforms where C or C++ nullptr is -1.  It does require careful cast-to-bool (well, cast-to/from-integral; 0 must convert to nullptr under the standard but the bit pattern of a null ptr doesn't have to be all 0s) code.

Comment: _There are even platforms where C++ nullptr is -1._ Could you please name one?

Comment: @evg no I cannot; but, if I decall, it is a gpu where 0 is a valid address, while -1 is not.  Might have been C rather than C++.